# How to remove subdirectory folders from the url using htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove the sub-folders from my site URL.

Below is the structure of my folders. I am not sure where to place my `.htaccess` file and what to have written in it:

- mysiteroot
  - subdir1
  - subdir2
    - index.php
    - page1.php
    - page2.php
    - page3.php

I have written the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ subdir1/subdir2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir1/$1
```

It seems to only work for the index with my `.htaccess` file placed in the mysiteroot folder.

How can I make the request for `page1.php` to show `www.mysiteroot.com/page1` instead of `www.mysiteroot.com/subdir1/subdir2/page1.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I had already written most of this before you posted your solution. Posting anyway as a more general solution that readers may find useful.*

---

> How can I make the request for `page1.php` to show `www.example.com/page1` instead of `www.example.com/subdir1/subdir2/page1.php`?

You do this by physically changing the URLs in your application, not in `.htaccess`. Once the URLs have been changed in your application, the request is then for `www.example.com/page1`, the visible URL that is shown to your users (not `page.php`). You then use mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` to *internally rewrite* the visible URL back to the real/hidden filesystem path: `/subdir1/subdir2/page1.php`. (But I suspect you already know this, since your code is doing the right kind of thing.)

In your file hierarchy diagram, you appear to show `subdir2` at the same level as `subdir1`? However, your code and URL structure suggests `subdir2` is a subdirectory of `subdir1`. I'll assume the later.

You basically need to do two things:

1. Rewrite all requests to `/subdir1/subdir2/` (except for requests that map directly to files or directories).
2. Append the `.php` file extension to requests that don't already have a file extension.

Try something like the following in the `.htaccess` file in the document root, ie. `mysiteroot/.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request has already been rewritten
# Or maps to an existing file then stop here.
# (Can't test for dir here since would not rewrite the doc root)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# No file extension on request then append .php and rewrite to subdir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)
RewriteRule !\.[a-z0-4]{2,4}$ /subdir1/subdir2/%1.php [NC,L]

# All remaining requests simply get rewritten to the subdir
RewriteRule (.*) /subdir1/subdir2/$1 [L]
```

Any request for `/path/to/file` (that does not directly map to a file) gets *internally rewritten* to `/subdir1/subdir2/path/to/file.php`.

The first `RewriteCond` directive ensures we don't rewrite requests that have already been rewritten to the subdirectory, thus preventing a rewrite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution that fit what I wanted to do. Online people provide a generate answer, but the issue is I do not intend to use the same page names without extensions to refer to my pages. This means I keep a file with the list of main pages.

Below are the details of my solution:
- Place the htaccess file in my root folder
- Refer to the pages in the subdirectories using an absolute reference

htaccess file content:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes #prevents access to folders
RewriteRule ^page1?$ ./subdir2/page1.php
RewriteRule ^page2?$ ./subdir2/page2.php
```

With this, all the pages in the htaccess will work as if they were in the root dir. So if you are to call a page that is not a main page and is in a sub folder, refer to it at that time going from the root folder

Simple solutions work best at times

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Your solution is indeed simpler than your question suggests! However, there are a few things to "check" in the directives you have posted. You probably want to remove the `?` in the `RewriteRule` _pattern(s)_ , eg. `^page1?$`. This is a regex, so the `?` makes the preceding char optional. This pattern would match "page1" and "page". You should also remove the `.` (dot) prefix on the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ (at best it's entirely superfluous). You should include the `L` flag on your directives. And Apache does not support line-end comments.